# PHP, PDO, MYSQL - how to order rows from two different tables by timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql

We have 2 different tables with such structure:

**dogs_table:**

- id
- dog_posts
- dog_date

**cats_table:**

- id
- cat_posts
- cat_date

In the browser I want to display posts from dogs and cats in such timeline:
[timeline image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsLbI.png)

So dog_posts should be on the left side and cat_posts on the right.
I spent already several days on solving this and it came clear to me that if I want to display posts in an appropriate way I must combine both tables and display posts by date(s) they were submitted.

Here is an example :

```
'SELECT * FROM dogs_table, cats_table ORDER BY dogs_table.dog_date, cats_table.cat_date DESC';
```

When I'm trying to display values in the browser they appear very chaotic, crashing it.
Also, I tried to use several UNION ways but it doesn't work right either. I'm asking for help with the right query and right way to combine both tables and display posts by the date they were submitted if it's even possible to do so.

Comment: make it one table

Comment: Yes, that would be easiest way but what if dogs and cats will have million posts, how would I maintain such table?

Comment: just like any other table in the world

Comment: Hm, I'm somehow still not sure that keeping two rows with posts in one table is a good idea... Especially if I would like to make additions in future. Or I am totally wrong and it's okay?

Comment: Yes, you are totally wrong. Similar data should be always stored in a single table. This is a cornerstone rule of a relational database design.

Comment: Okay, but what if two users will try to submit dog_post and cat_post at the same time?

Comment: what if two users will try to submit dog_post and dog_post at the same time with your current design?

Comment: I got you, no more silly questions! :) Will try it with one table, and see how it is. Thank you very much!

Comment: Ah..here we go, how do I define unique id row for both dogs and cats posts if there can be only one unique id row? ...

Comment: well use that unique id. what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **UNION** to combine two tables and sort the results using **ORDER BY** clause.

The following MySQL query should get the results for what you are trying to achieve.

```
SELECT cat_posts as posts, cat_date as date, 'cats' as type from cats_table
UNION
SELECT dog_posts as posts, dog_date as date, 'dogs' as type from dogs_table
ORDER BY date desc
```

When querying individual tables, you will use an alias for each columns (posts and date) so that you can use ORDER BY on date column.

You will also need to identify which rows are from **dogs_table** table and which are from **cats_table** table.

So, you will be adding a dummy column named **type** and set its values to *dogs* and *cats* for **dogs_table** and **cats_table** respectively.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But it doesn't work as I need it... It unites two tables and displays dog_posts and cat_posts as one table. But I need it to be in two different columns... :(